# How a super function can access another super function inside a child class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, superclass

```js
//parent class
module.exports = class Parser {
    constructor() {}
    tokenize(s) {}
    fixDates(rule) {}

}


//child class
const Parser = require('./parser');
module.exports = class ParserEn extends Parser {
    constructor() {}

    run(str) {
        super.tokenize(str.toLowerCase()).forEach(function (s) {

            //here i want to acces to another function in the parent class
            super.fixDates(rule); //I get this error: 'super' keyword unexpected here
        });
    }
}
```

Hi, 
As you can see in the above code, I have two functions in the parent class and a function in the child class. In the run function inside the child class, I can access to the to the tokenize by using keyword "super". However, I need to access the fixDates function too, but I do get this error: "'super' keyword unexpected here" . Would be great if someone helps me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super()` in the constructor of the child class. You should also use an arrow function in the `forEach` callback, to preserve the `this` context:

```js
class Parser {
  constructor() {}
  tokenize(s) { return [...s]; }
  fixDates(rule) { console.log(rule); }
}

class ParserEn extends Parser {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  run(str) {
    super.tokenize(str.toLowerCase()).forEach((s) => {
      super.fixDates(s);
    });
  }
}

const parseren = new ParserEn();
parseren.run('foo');
```